# C++ No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list when calling std::replace()

Tags: c++, overloading

I am doing my custom image file format to display images in CLI but i need to convert `size_t` to `std::string`:

```cpp
namespace csfo {
 class Res {
  public:
   char* BLANK_DATA = "...";
 };

 ...

 inline char* generate(int COLOR, size_t x, size_t y, bool verbose) {
  csfo::Res RES;

  ...

  std::string dimenssions[2] = {
   std::to_string(x),
   std::to_string(y)
  };

  std::string DATA = RES.BLANK_DATA;
  DATA = DATA.replace(DATA.begin(), DATA.end(), "[X_SIZE]", dimenssions[0]);

  ...
 };

 ...
}
```

But i get this error when i try to call std::to_string()

No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list c/c++(304)

Can someone please help me?
Thanks.

I except my code to work

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense, what are you trying to replace and with what?

Comment: `std::string::replace` is not for replacing occurances of one string with another; it's for replacing one part of the string the function is called for with a different string. In your case you're passing the whole string as range to replace and then pass 2 strings to replace the string with...

Comment: I guess you are trying to replace `[X_SIZE]` in the `DATA` string with the value of `dimensions[0]`, but `replace` doesn't work like that. It does not search for a substring, if that is what you want to do then you need to do the searching yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means that your compiler didn't find any matching "variant" (overloading) of [std::string::replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace)  method.

To replace given text in `std::string`, you should:

1. Find the text position and determine the text length.
2. Check if found.
3. Replace if found.

E.g:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//! Replaces the first occurence of @param text in @param textTemplate with @param toInsert.
// Since C++17 use std::string_view for @param text.
void replace_text(std::string& textTemplate, const std::string& text, const std::string& toInsert)
{
    const std::size_t pos = textTemplate.find(text);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        /// Given @param text not found.
        return;
    }
    
    textTemplate.replace(pos, text.length(), toInsert);
}

int main()
{
    static const std::string X_SIZE = "[X_SIZE]";
    std::string DATA = "My data template with [X_SIZE] occurence.";
    replace_text(DATA, X_SIZE, std::to_string(4));
    std::cout << DATA << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The member`csfo::Res::BLANK_DATA` should be `const char*` or `std::string_view` or `std::string` but not just `char*` - because you cannot modify it when pointing to [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines of what you are trying to do I think this is the correct code

```
size_t n = DATA.find("[X_SIZE]"); // find where [X_SIZE] is in DATA
DATA.replace(n, n + 8, dimenssions[0]); // and replace it with dimenssions[0]
```

There's no error checking in this code (i.e. what if [X_SIZE] is not found), and the hard coded constant `8` should be factored out (eight is the length of "[X_SIZE]").